# How to trigger an image swap using jquery when mouse over a mapped area of an img using usemap

Tags: jquery, hover

I have the following code:

```
<img src="images/menu-home-off.png" width="153" height="37" border="0" usemap="#menuhome" />
<map name="menuhome" id="menuhome">
<area shape="poly" coords="12,0,153,0,153,35,1,35" href="#" />
</map>
```

The map (menuhome) only takes up a selection of the image (menu-home-off.png). The intended objective is to have menu-home-off.png swap to menu-home-on.png when the mouse rolls over the map (menuhome) area of the image.

I have found many jquery mouse over image swap code snippets, but can't quite work out how something like this could be applied. There will also be numerous maps/images on the page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doesn't this work for you?

```
$('#menuhome area').on('hover', function(e){
    console.log("hovered.");
});
```

Example: 
http://jsfiddle.net/6ReMp/3/

Comment: He doesn't have an id on the area.

Comment: I edited it, thanks Jay. But the author wrote that there will be **be numerous maps/images on the page**, so he has to use a more concrete selector anyway (`#menuhome area` for example). Except if all areas do exactly the same.

Comment: I know - I suggested the same thing in my answer. It may not have been clear to the OP.

Answer (score 1):

`$('area').mouseover(function()` .... does not work for you?

In the case where you are adding multiple areas make sure that you give each one an id or a class that makes it easier to interact with.